# Menu item inside NavigationView onClick is triggered only on double click

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-arrayadapter, navigation-drawer

I've created menu for `NavigationView` by adding `ListView` inside my `NavigationView`. Then I made custom `ArrayAdapter` where each menu item is added. Each menu item has custom xml layout attached to it. Root of this layout is used by `onClickListener` triggering function passed to menu item class as parameter.

Everything works perfectly, but as I click on item, it will not trigger this function, only as I double click. Why is this behavior happening?

Code:
This is class for menu item (multiple different items are extending this class)
Not every menu item has click event (for example section headers)

```
abstract class DrawerItem(var itemName: String, var imgResID: Int, var onClick: (() -> Unit)? = null)
```

This is how `onClick` is called inside `getView` function for some menu items:

```
val root: LinearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.root)
root.setOnClickListener {
     menuItem.onClick?.invoke()
}
```

XML layout for NavigationView:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/navigation_header_container"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </LinearLayout>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lst_menu_items"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

Layout of one menu item type:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:background="@drawable/navig_menu_selector"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/navig_ico"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/navig_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_medium"
            style="@style/navig_item_text"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/custom_separator"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where is your **root** layout? Also if you are using ListView then you can implement **OnItemClickListener** listener

Comment: added root layout

Comment: Also it looks like root layout click area is covered by child views. As I click to corner of menu item it works, but inside center it is not. I've added duplicateParentState to send each click up to parent but it seems to not working at all

Comment: check if your custom row of listview is clickable and consuming the touch event

Comment: It is clickable. I've added android:background="@drawable/navig_menu_selector" which is onPressed selector and it is changing color. But I have to click twice to invoke function inside on click. It looks like that first time it is initializing click listener and second time it is actually working.

Comment: so you got your problem right?

Comment: Well, I dont know what is a problem. Why is that listener not working on first click.

Comment: Your drawable selector is your problem

Comment: Fixed, root cannot be focusable and focusable in touch mode if its part of the list view. OnClickListener will not work

Answer (score 0):

Clear the app's cache or delete it altogether and try downloading it again. I don't know the cause, but I solved the problem.